# Clean way to acces nested variable properties from the $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, properties, nested-properties

I want to access same variable properties in a java script file but because are too many properties the code looks a bit to ugly. I have the next code:

```
$scope.invoice = new Invoice();

$scope.operations = {
    editingLine: {},
    isNewLine: false,
    isEditOpen: false
};

$scope.modify = function (invoiceLine) {

    if ($scope.operations.isEditOpen) return;

    let originalLine = $scope.invoice.invoiceLines.find(line => line.id = invoiceLine.id);
    tempLine = angular.copy(originalLine);
    $scope.operations.editingLine[invoiceLine.id] = true;
    $scope.operations.isEditOpen = true;
};
```

Is there any way to access the the property `invoiceLine` which is set on the object `invoice`, or the property `isEditOpen` which is set on the object `operations` in cleaner way? I have a lot of repetition of this code in my file and I want to find a clener way to access properties like this.

I know that I can to define a variable var `operations = $scope.operations` and to access the property  `operations.isEditOpen` when I need this value but still, I want something more simpler because I don't want to create variable for all objects from the scope.

Is there any way to create a `function` with two `params` (`objectFromScope, neededProperty`) that can return the requiered property value from a variable which is set on the scope? Or is there any better way to do not have such much code when I want to access an object property from the scope?

PS: I can also do something like this:

```
let editingLine = $scope.operations.editingLine;
    let isNewLine = $scope.operations.isNewLine;
    let isEditOpen = $scope.operations.isEditOpen;

$scope.modify = function (invoiceLine) {

        if (isEditOpen) return;

        let originalLine = invoiceLines.find(line => line.id = invoiceLine.id);
        tempLine = angular.copy(originalLine);
        editingLine[invoiceLine.id] = true;
        isEditOpen = true;
    };
```

But is this a good approach?

Comment: "because I don't want to create variable for all objects from the scope" - why not?

Comment: btw, re: `let editingLine = $scope.operations.editingLine;` - if that code is in the global scope then it will only make a copy of `editingLine` just once. It isn't a live _view_ of the value.

Comment: "Is there any way to access the the property `invoiceLine` which is set on the object `invoice`" - do you mean `invoiceLines`, not `invoiceLine`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to create a function with two params `( objectFromScope, neededProperty )` that can return the required property value from a variable which is set on the scope? Or is there any better way to do not have such much code when I want to access an object property from the scope?

Yes, but I don't see how it saves you any trouble. It will also make it harder to switch to TypeScript (though you can make it work with `keyof` if you don't want to dereference an entire property path).

But this is that function:

```
function getPropertyValue( objectFromScope, neededProperty ) {
    
    const pathComponents = neededProperty.split( '.' );
    
    let obj = objectFromScope;
    for( const component of pathComponents ) {
        obj = obj[ component ];
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Usage:

```
$scope.invoice = new Invoice();

$scope.operations = {
    editingLine: {},
    isNewLine: false,
    isEditOpen: false
};

$scope.modify = function( invoiceLine ) {

    if ($scope.operations.isEditOpen) return;

    const lines = getPropertyValue( $scope, 'invoice.invoiceLines' );
    let originalLine = lines.find(line => line.id = invoiceLine.id);

    tempLine = angular.copy(originalLine);
    $scope.operations.editingLine[invoiceLine.id] = true;
    $scope.operations.isEditOpen = true;
};
```

...but this really doesn't make your code any easier to read or maintain. Instead it makes it worse because doing things this way is very non-idiomatic for JavaScript and AngularJS: anyone else who works on this project will stare at the code for a few minutes and scratch their head before wondering out loud why you're doing this in the first place.